# How to verify the presence of a script on multiple web pages?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I have a set of web pages where I need to verify that a certain script is present. A have a lot of pages to verify so I would like to automate this part of testing. How can a create a sequence with selenium (or any other solution) where I have something of an array of webpages which is used for repetition of the same check through all these webpages? In other words, how can I cover a set of pages with one test? Because the check is the same for all of the pages.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most programming languages support list of items and loops, some pseudo code:

- Create a list of websites/urls to visit (e.g. array)
- Start WebDriver
- Foreach url in list (e.g. a loop to go over each item in the list)

  - Visit the page (e.g. `driver.get(url)`)
  - Get the page source (e.g. `driver.page_source`)
  - Check the page source contains something unique to the script you are looking for (e.g. `page_source.find("something unique")`)
  - If script not found log url

Comment: It seems that selenium does not have the find() method for the String which getPageSource() method returns. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose I can use contains().

Comment: As you didn't provide the programming language you used I took Python examples, but other languages provider similar functions. Selenium does also not have a contains, the String getPageSource() probably has.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an externally downloaded script you can intercept the traffic and look for the file, it's easy with Puppeteer and less straightforward with other frameworks. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag)